# Looking for the title of a fantasy/sci-fi book that incorporated Conway's Game of Life

Tags: story-identification

It was a setting where there were small machines that played life, their backs would flip between white/black.  The two players set up initial conditions on two sides of the board and (I think) the goal was to get one of your designs over to the other side.  Probably late 80s early 90s.

Comment: Wil McCarthy's [*Bloom*](http://www.amazon.com/Bloom-Wil-McCarthy/dp/0345485378) has people playing with Conway's *Game of Life,* but not as a competitive or multi-player game.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like ["Glory Season"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1866) by David Brin, first published in 1993. One of the pastimes in Brin's novel is called Life, and it's essentially Conway's Game of Life. The basic mechanics of the game pieces are described like so:

> The paddles sensed the status of neighboring tiles during a game, so that each piece would "know" whether to show its white or its black face at a given time.
>
> <sup><sub>["Glory Season" Chapter 2](http://www.davidbrin.com/gloryseason2.html)</sub></sup>

And the rules of the competitive version are described later. I don't have access to the full book, but [the Google Books preview](https://books.google.ca/books?id=uni-WIC4keAC&ots=fZMIBQaYyn&pg=PA225#v=onepage&q&f=false) provides some description for the competitive version:

> Two men - or teams of men - faced off at opposite ends of a board consisting of anywhere from two score to several hundred intersecting horizontal and vertical lines. During the crucial preparation phase, each side took turns strategically laying rows of game pieces in the squares between the lines - choosing to place them either white or black side up - until the board was full. Simple rules were programmed into the pieces, or sometimes into the board [itself<sup>1</sup>]
>
> *[...]*
>
> [T]he game was played as a battle between two teams. Their objective: to lay down starting conditions such that when play commenced, the sweep of shapes would carry their way, wiping clear their opponents' territory, so that the last oases of "life" would be on their side of the board.
>
> <sup><sub>"Glory Season" Chapter 10</sub></sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> As I mentioned, I don't have access to the full book, so I'm speculating on the word here. Anyone who *does* have the book is welcome to correct me.

Comment: This sounds exactly right!  Thanks, time to go find a copy :)

Comment: I believe that's correct. They also use the game as a code, with starting positions that would evolve over many generations to a stable message just long enough for the receiver to see. Is that right?