# Please identify this novel that features the Game of Life

Tags: story-identification, aliens, alternate-history

Name of alternate history novel with a rigid class society that has the Game of Life throughout the book.It was believed that only men were intelligent enough to play the game. This novel takes place in the future. Can anyone help me and identify this excellent novel?

Comment: This novel takes place in future

Comment: Ox by Piers Anthony? Possible duplicate of this question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216305/70s-sci-fi-story-including-describing-conways-solitaire-game-life/216319#216319

Comment: Bloom by Wil McCarthy? Possible duplicate of this question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127146/a-novel-about-humanity-after-the-earth-has-been-devoured-by-foam

Comment: Glory Season by David Brin?  Possible duplicate of this question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84323/looking-for-the-title-of-a-fantasy-sci-fi-book-that-incorporated-conways-game-o/84329#84329

Comment: [Conway's "Game of Life"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life)? It can be "played" (actually, just run, as it is not a "Game" at all) by a syntactic machine based on a Z80, who would think that only men were intelligent enough to "play" the game? The only thing I can think of is David Brin's "Glory Season" but I never got the point of why a GoL was shoehorned into that story.

Comment: Aliens makes me think of Player of Games by Iain M Banks https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Player_of_Games

Comment: Or, alternately, do they just call it the "game of life"?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer But we're talking fiction here. Maybe this one has a version of Game of Life you can play. Can't be tougher to do than faster-than-light travel.

Comment: The Martian in S. M. Stirling's excellent In the Halls of the Crimson Kings are obsessed with a game which comes out The Game of Life in English, but everyone plays it.

Comment: @Pete You should post *Glory Season* as an answer. Compare the OP's "It was believed that only men were intelligent enough to play the game" with this quote from the novel via [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=uni-WIC4keAC&q=life#v=snippet&q=batty&f=false) (p. 229): "This game was another matter. If there were women on Stratos who had ever achieved expert status at Life, they were almost certainly labeled terminally strange."

Answer (score 6):

Most likely [Glory Season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glory_Season) by David Brin.
If so, it's a duplicate of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84323/looking-for-the-title-of-a-fantasy-sci-fi-book-that-incorporated-conways-game-o/84329#84329). See link for details of the book.

Also credit due to **user14111** who found this quote in Google Books

> This game was another matter. If there were women on Stratos who had ever achieved expert status at Life, they were almost certainly labeled terminally strange.